# Console.Readline() not working show weird symbol on MacOS

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and doing a project mimicking how chat app work. My idea is to send a message from the client to the server and then return a message from the server to the client. But when I want to write something to the Console.Readline() on the client side, it shows weird diamond symbol with a question mark inside.
This is not happening to the server.

My client code:

```
namespace client {
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        Console.WriteLine("Server IP address: ");
        string _ipTemp = Console.ReadLine()!;
        var _ip = IPAddress.Parse(_ipTemp);

        var _client = new UdpClient();

        _client.Connect(_ip, 1308);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("#Client >>>");
            var _text = Console.ReadLine()!;
            var _buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_text);
            _client.Send(_buffer, _buffer.Length);
            var _ipendpoint = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
            _buffer = _client.Receive(ref _ipendpoint);
            var _response = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_buffer);
            Console.WriteLine("#Server >>> {0}", _response);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The diamond symbols mean you're printing non-UTF8 encoded data, but also depends on the terminal settings

Comment: Have you tried with ``Encoding.UTF8``?